# How to install Android widget from an Android Activity?

Tags: android-widget

I want to install the widget from the Android Activity. After doing this the widget should be available along with the list of other previously installed widgets. For this, i have created a custom widget. But dont know how to install the widget from the Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this. We have to mention the Widget in the manifest file as a receiver. Then it will create the widget. We can use the widget by long press on the home screen and tap widget to place on home screen. I got the answer after lot of search. The usage is ,

```
<receiver
        android:name="MyWidgetProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/widic"
        android:label="Example Widget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```